# Create a duplicate flag based on all column values pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Ind_ID     Team_ID      Status      Date
1          1            Win         13-08-2019
1          1            Lost        14-10-2019
1          1            Win         13-08-2019
1          1            Win         13-08-2019
```

I am newbie in python. In the above dataframe I would like to add one column which indicates the duplicates. We consider duplicates as row to row match.

```
Ind_ID     Team_ID      Status      Date           Duplicate
1          1            Win         13-08-2019     No
1          1            Lost        14-10-2019     No
1          1            Win         13-08-2019     Yes
1          1            Win         13-08-2019     Yes
```

Please note that the first one the same should not be flagged as duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Duplicate'] = np.where(df.duplicated(keep=False), 'Yes','No')
print (df)
   Ind_ID  Team_ID Status        Date Duplicate
0       1        1    Win  13-08-2019       Yes
1       1        1   Lost  14-10-2019        No
2       1        1    Win  13-08-2019       Yes
3       1        1    Win  13-08-2019       Yes
```

Or if need test rows by pairs add helper column for groups by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df['Duplicate'] = np.where(df.assign(new=df.index // 2).duplicated(keep=False), 'Yes','No')
print (df)
   Ind_ID  Team_ID Status        Date Duplicate
0       1        1    Win  13-08-2019        No
1       1        1   Lost  14-10-2019        No
2       1        1    Win  13-08-2019       Yes
3       1        1    Win  13-08-2019       Yes
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.assign(new=df.index // 2))
   Ind_ID  Team_ID Status        Date  new
0       1        1    Win  13-08-2019    0
1       1        1   Lost  14-10-2019    0
2       1        1    Win  13-08-2019    1
3       1        1    Win  13-08-2019    1
```